# Generating PDF on WP8.1 Fails to Wrap Lines

Tags: c#, pdf, windows-phone-8.1

I found a code in vb.Net that generate text to PDF and I tried to translate it in C# and it works
[How to generate PDF on Windows Phone in VB or C#](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lucian/archive/2013/08/15/how-to-generate-pdf-on-windows-phone-in-vb-or-c.aspx)
 but the problem of the text is long like a paragraph, so it will be not enter to the next line, it will show one line, and on the pdf show me only 6 or 7 words
this is how it show

[image]

and for the code is :

```
    private async void EditButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


         listitem = (e.OriginalSource as MenuFlyoutItem).DataContext as WritePadFileContent;
         //MessageDialog messageDialog = new MessageDialog(listitem.Name.ToString());
         //await messageDialog.ShowAsync(); 

        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(listitem.Name.ToString()+".pdf", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
        using (Stream stream = await WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(file))
        {
            var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
            List<long> xrefs = new List<long>();
            // PDF-HEADER
            writer.WriteLine("%PDF-1.2");
            // PDF-BODY. Convention is to start with a 4-byte binary comment
            // so everyone recognizes the pdf as binary. Then the file has
            // a load of numbered objects, #1..#7 in this case
            writer.Write("%"); writer.Flush();
            byte[] vbbyte = new byte[4] { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            stream.Write(vbbyte, 0, 4);
            stream.Flush();
            writer.WriteLine("");
            // #1; catalog - the overall container of the entire PDF
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Flush();
            xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("1 0 obj");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Catalog");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Pages 2 0 R");
            writer.WriteLine(">>");
            writer.WriteLine("endobj");
            // #2; page-list - we have only one child page
            writer.Flush(); stream.Flush(); xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("2 0 obj");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Pages");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Kids [3 0 R]");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Count 1");
            writer.WriteLine(">>");
            writer.WriteLine("endobj");
            // #3; page - this is our page. We specify size, font resources, and the contents
            writer.Flush(); stream.Flush(); xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("3 0 obj");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Page");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Parent 2 0 R");
            writer.WriteLine("  /MediaBox [0 0 612 792]"); // Default userspace units; 72/inch, origin at bottom left
            writer.WriteLine("  /Resources");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("    /ProcSet [/PDF/Text]"); // This PDF uses only the Text ability
            writer.WriteLine("    /Font");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("      /F0 4 0 R"); // I will define three fonts, #4, #5 and #6
            writer.WriteLine("      /F1 5 0 R");
            writer.WriteLine("      /F2 6 0 R");
            writer.WriteLine("    >>");
            writer.WriteLine("  >>");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Contents 7 0 R");
            writer.WriteLine(">>");
            writer.WriteLine("endobj");
            // #4, #5, #6; three font resources, all using fonts that are built into all PDF-viewers
            // We//re going to use WinAnsi character encoding, defined below.
            writer.Flush(); stream.Flush(); xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("4 0 obj");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Font");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Subtype /Type1");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding");
            writer.WriteLine("  /BaseFont /Times-Roman");
            writer.WriteLine(">>");
            writer.Flush(); stream.Flush(); xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("5 0 obj");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Font");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Subtype /Type1");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding");
            writer.WriteLine("  /BaseFont /Times-Bold");
            writer.WriteLine(">>");
            writer.Flush(); stream.Flush(); xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
            writer.WriteLine("6 0 obj");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Type /Font");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Subtype /Type1");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Encoding /WinAnsiEncoding");
            writer.WriteLine("  /BaseFont /Times-Italic");
            writer.WriteLine(">>");
            // #7; contents of page. This is written in postscript, fully described in
            // chapter 8 of the PDF 1.2 reference manual.
            writer.Flush(); stream.Flush(); xrefs.Add(stream.Position);
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendLine("BT");  // BT = begin text object, with text-units the same as userspace-units
            sb.AppendLine("/F0 40 Tf");  // Tf = start using the named font "F0" with size "40"
            sb.AppendLine("40 TL"); // TL = set line height to "40"
            sb.AppendLine("230.0 400.0 Td");// Td = position text point at coordinates "230.0", "400.0"
            sb.AppendLine("(Hello all)"); // Apostrophe = print the text, and advance to the next line
            sb.AppendLine("/F2 20 Tf");//
            sb.AppendLine("20 TL");//
            sb.AppendLine("0.0 0.2 1.0 rg");// rg = set fill color to RGB("0.0", "0.2", "1.0")
            //sb.AppendLine("(olaaaa" + "é" + ") '");
            //sb.AppendLine("(olaaaa" + "é" + ") '");
            sb.AppendLine("(" + listitem.Description.ToString() + ") '");

            sb.AppendLine("ET"); //
            writer.WriteLine("7 0 obj");
            writer.WriteLine("<<");
            writer.WriteLine("  /Length " + sb.Length);
            writer.WriteLine(">>");
            writer.WriteLine("stream");

            writer.Write(sb.ToString());

            writer.WriteLine("endstream");

            writer.WriteLine("endobj"); ;



            // PDF-XREFS. This part of the PDF is an index table into every object #1..#7

            // that we defined.

            writer.Flush(); stream.Flush(); var xref_pos = stream.Position;

            writer.WriteLine("xref");

            writer.WriteLine("1 " + xrefs.Count);

            foreach (object xref in xrefs)
            {

                writer.WriteLine("{0:0000000000} {1:00000} n", xref, 0);

            }



            // PDF-TRAILER. Every PDF ends with this trailer.

            writer.WriteLine("trailer");

            writer.WriteLine("<<");

            writer.WriteLine("  /Size " + xrefs.Count);

            writer.WriteLine("  /Root 1 0 R");

            writer.WriteLine(">>");

            writer.WriteLine("startxref");

            writer.WriteLine(xref_pos);

            writer.WriteLine("%%EOF");

            writer.Flush(); stream.Flush();

        }





        await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
    }
```

So if there another code can help me with windows Phone 8.1 C# or another example.
this code add the name of pdf file

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(listitem.Name.ToString()+".pdf", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

this code give me to add description into pdf

```
sb.AppendLine("(" + listitem.Description.ToString() + ") '");
```

Comment: Maybe don't copy code you don't understand.

Comment: that code was vb.net and I translate some of it to C#

Comment: PDFs don't support automatic line breaks in text. Anytime you see what appears to be an automatic line break you are actually seeing at least two different "draw text here" commands. If you look at the comments you'll see a good starting point that says `position text point at coordinates "230.0", "400.0"`

Comment: You should read the PDF specification (1000 pages or so) if you want to use the code above. Or you could use a dedicated PDF library that supports automatic text wrapping.

Comment: @ Mihai Iancu , so u know any PDF library that supports automatic text wrapping?

Comment: SO rules do not allow 3rd party library recommendations. You should ask here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this last code I am stuck, and its impossible to work with it because it is written in postscript and I can't find the manual to the PDF 1.2 reference related to chapter 8.

But I tried to use another library and it work with WP8.1 C#
Xfinium an easy library, so you most download the library [Xfinium](http://xfiniumpdf.com/) 
this is a screen shot of the code (2nd button)

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using Xfinium.Pdf;
using Xfinium.Pdf.Actions;
using Xfinium.Pdf.Core;
using Xfinium.Pdf.Graphics;
using Xfinium.Pdf.Graphics.FormattedContent;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace App40
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Invoked when this page is about to be displayed in a Frame.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e">Event data that describes how this page was reached.
        /// This parameter is typically used to configure the page.</param>
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Prepare page for display here.

            // TODO: If your application contains multiple pages, ensure that you are
            // handling the hardware Back button by registering for the
            // Windows.Phone.UI.Input.HardwareButtons.BackPressed event.
            // If you are using the NavigationHelper provided by some templates,
            // this event is handled for you.
        }

        private  void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }


        //this is a tutrila can help you with simple text
        private async void Button_Click1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("a.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (Stream stream = await WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(file))
            {
                PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();
                PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();
                // Create a standard font with Helvetica face and 24 point size
                PdfStandardFont helvetica = new PdfStandardFont(PdfStandardFontFace.Helvetica, 24);
                // Create a solid RGB red brush.
                PdfBrush brush = new PdfBrush(PdfRgbColor.Red);
                // Draw the text on the page.
                string cha = "title";
                page.Graphics.DrawString(cha, helvetica, brush, 250, 50);
                // Draw the text on the page. max tableau 50
                string ch = "azj aeiajiahfioe foiehfioehfiehfie feifjaepfjaepofjaepo fpaejfpeafjaefaefhevpzevje vjepzvihzev zep";
                page.Graphics.DrawString(ch, helvetica, brush, 10, 100);

                document.Save(stream);


            }
            await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);

            //FileStream input = File.OpenRead("optionalcontent-src.pdf");
            //PdfFile file = new PdfFile(input);

        }

        //this is a tutrila can help you with paragraph block
        private async void Button_Click2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("a.pdf", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            using (Stream stream = await WindowsRuntimeStorageExtensions.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(file))
            {
                string paragraph2Block1Text = "The development style is based on fixed document model, where each page is created as needed " +
                "and content is placed at fixed position using a grid based layout.\r\n" +
                "This gives you access to all PDF features, whether you want to create a simple file " +
                "or you want to create a transparency knockout group at COS level, and lets you build more complex models on top of the library.";

                PdfStandardFont textFont = new PdfStandardFont(PdfStandardFontFace.TimesRoman, 12);

                PdfFormattedParagraph paragraph2 = new PdfFormattedParagraph();
                paragraph2.SpacingAfter = 3;
                paragraph2.FirstLineIndent = 10;
                paragraph2.HorizontalAlign = PdfStringHorizontalAlign.Justified;
                paragraph2.LineSpacingMode = PdfFormattedParagraphLineSpacing.Multiple;
                paragraph2.LineSpacing = 1.2;
                paragraph2.Blocks.Add(new PdfFormattedTextBlock(paragraph2Block1Text, textFont));

                PdfFormattedContent formattedContent = new PdfFormattedContent();
                formattedContent.Paragraphs.Add(paragraph2);

                PdfFixedDocument document = new PdfFixedDocument();
                PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();

                page.Graphics.DrawFormattedContent(formattedContent, 50, 50, 500, 700);
                page.Graphics.CompressAndClose();

                document.Save(stream);
            }
            await Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
        }
    }
}
```